# Replace image when update in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Both function are same and the store function are running perfectly but update function have some errors

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $employee = new Employee;

    $employee->phone = $request->emp_num;
    $employee->name = $request->emp_name;
    $employee->email = $request->emp_email;
    $employee->address = $request->emp_add;

    if ($request->has('emp_image')) {
         $image = $request->file('emp_image');
         $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

         $savePath = env('UPLOAD_PATH');
         $image->move($savePath, $filename);

         $employee->image = $request->file('emp_image');
     }

     $employee->save();

     return redirect()->route('employee.index')
         ->with('success','Employee has been created successfully.');
}

public function update(Request $request, employee $employee)
{
    $employee->name = $request->emp_name;
    $employee->email = $request->emp_email;
    $employee->phone = $request->emp_num;
    $employee->address = $request->emp_add;

    if ($request->has('emp_img')) {
         $image = $request->file('emp_img');
         $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

         $savePath = env('UPLOAD_PATH');
         $image->move($savePath, $filename);

         $employee->image = $request->file('emp_img');
    }

    $employee->update();

    return "Updated";

    return redirect()->route('employee.index')
        ->with('success', $request->emp_name.' Employee data has been Updated successfully.');
}
```

##### The error

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you datadump $image?

Comment: "_Both function are same_" They are not: the working method has `$request->file('emp_image');` while the non-working has `$request->file('emp_img');`. Are they named the same in your form?

Comment: @Stoff Don't really think this is related to the error, if the request didn't have that field `if($request->has('emp_img')) {` would not trigger and `$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();` wouldn't be called

Comment: While that is true, what if the field existed but returned NULL as contents? If that is the case, should this not be triggered?

Comment: @brombeer $request->file('emp_image'); in store name is same and $request->file('emp_img'); in update are also same.

Comment: Oh my god, you are using `env` inside a controller... you must use `config` because if you just `php artisan config:cache`, then you will have no values back from `env`... There is a whole section dedicated on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#environment-configuration) talking about this...

Answer (score 1):

To store data with image

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $category = new Category();

    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
    $imageName = $request->file('image')
        ->storeAs('images/category_photo', $imageName, 'public');

    $category->name = $request->name;
    $category->image = $imageName;
    $category->save();

    if ($category) {
        return redirect()->route('category.index')
            ->with('success', 'Category Added Successfully');
    }
}
```

To edit data with images and delete the existing image

```php
public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $category->name = $request->name;

    if ($request->file('image')) {
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();

        Storage::delete('public/'.$category->image);

        $category->image = $request->file('image')
        ->storeAs('images/category_photo', $imageName, 'public');
    }

    $save = $category->save();

    if ($save) {
        return redirect()->route('category.index')
            ->with('success', 'Category Updated Successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is nearly right, but not quite. You are not checking if `file('image')` has content or not, if it has no content then will return `null` so `->storeAs` will throw a `PHP Fatal Error`... Also, none of yours `store` and `update` methods are returning something if the `save` failed (returned `false`)... you have weird code...